# Spring Tool Suite 3.9.1, does not allow choosing Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

In the [New Spring Starter Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE3A9.gif), for Version 2.0.1, (STS 3.9.1), Apache Camel is not available to including as a dependency. Is this not supported or am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that Camel currently supports Spring Boot 1.5, and not Spring Boot 2.0..  [as per the release notes here](http://camel.apache.org/camel-2210-release.html)